# Returning rows in CSV based on column match to values in other CSV

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a piece of code I use to retrieve specific rows in a large usage data file for specific items which I write out as a list. For any matches in the DOI field the entire row is retrieved.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

df_usage = pd.read_csv(r"usage_data.csv", encoding='latin-1')
article_usage = df.loc[df['DOI'] .isin(['DOI_1','DOI_2','DOI_3'])]

article_usage.to_csv(r"article_usage.csv")
```

However, I now need to retrieve a much larger amount of rows and so instead of writing out a list in my code with each item I want to change this to read a CSV containing all the items for which I need to retrieve rows in the data file.

```
df_usage = pd.read_csv(r"usage_data.csv", encoding='latin-1')
df_item_list = pd.read_csv(r"item_list.csv", encoding='latin-1', header=None)
article_usage = df_usage.loc[df_usage['DOI'] .isin(df_item_list)]

article_usage.to_csv(r"article_usage.csv")
```

The usage data file is a large CSV (100K+ rows and 53 columns with "DOI" being the column I am trying to match by).

```
           DOI      Jan    Feb   Mar
    0     DOI_1      27    123   345
    1     DOI_2      89    34    234
    2     DOI_3      65    56    102
```

The item list CSV is just a file containing each DOI I am trying to match.

```
        0
0     DOI_1
1     DOI_2
2     DOI_3
```

When I run the above the article_usage.csv file will only contain the data for the first item in my article list. How can i modify this code to retrieve data for all the items in the list? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your [mre] should always include a minimal example of the data. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to filter rows based on the `item_list.csv` you could try:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from pandas import DataFrame

df = pd.read_csv(r"usage_data.csv", encoding='latin-1')
df_items = pd.read_csv(r"item_list.csv", encoding='latin-1', names=['DOI'])
article_usage = df.loc[df['DOI'] .isin(df_items['DOI'])]
article_usage.to_csv(r"article_usage.csv", index=False)
```

This assumes `item_list.csv` has no header and is just a list of required DOI entries.